# Trying to get last known location when a button is pressed in Android app (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

As the title states, I want to know the last location when a button is pressed, but it's not working and I'm not sure what's wrong. in my Android Manifest I have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and for my activity I have:

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_cow)


    // updates the variables with these values
    Submit.setOnClickListener {
        checkPermissions()

        getLastKnownLocation()
```

and my two methods I'm using are :

```
private fun checkPermissions() {
    val PERMISSION_REQUEST = 10
    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST)
}
```

and:

```
fun getLastKnownLocation() {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        checkPermissions()
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                if (location != null) {
                    // use your location object
                    // get latitude , longitude and other info from this
                    longitude = location.longitude
                    latitude = location.latitude
                    d("getlastknown Lat:", latitude.toString())
                    d("getlastknown Lon:", longitude.toString())
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors. Nothing shows up in my log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not 100% sure that you will get last known location!

The location object may be null in the following situations:

> - Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be null even if the last location was previously retrieved because
>     disabling location also clears the cache.
> - The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a    new device or a device that has been restored to factory
>     settings.
> - Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location
>     after the services restarted. To avoid this situation you can create a
>     new client and request location updates yourself.

Here is more [info](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known) from official docs